# Split R column without delimiter

Tags: r, split, tidyr, delimiter

How do I split my column "ID" without a delimiter? Here is my example dataframe:

`df=data.frame(ID=c("1a", "1", "2b", "2c", "1yolk", "3", "3yolk"), length=c(5.5, 6.7, 7.1, 8.2, 4.5, 2.2, 3.5))`

How would I split the ID column into two columns, the first column (n) being only the first number and the second column (view) being everything that comes after that first number. Here's what I want the resulting data frame to look like:

`df=data.frame(n=c("1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "3", "3"), view=c("a", "", "b", "c", "yolk", "", "yolk"), length=c(5.5, 6.7, 7.1, 8.2, 4.5, 2.2, 3.5))`

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr::extract` you can specify the regex on how you want to split two column.

```
tidyr::extract(df, ID, c('n', 'view'), '(\\d+)(.*)', convert = TRUE)
  n view length
1 1    a    5.5
2 1         6.7
3 2    b    7.1
4 2    c    8.2
5 1 yolk    4.5
6 3         2.2
7 3 yolk    3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub`and backreference, `\\1` to refer back to the string-initial number, `\\2` to anything that follows it:

```
df$n <- sub("(^\\d)(.*$)", "\\1", df$ID)
df$view <- sub("(^\\d)(.*$)", "\\2", df$ID)
```

If there are more than 1 digit, use `\\d+`.

Result:

```
df
     ID length n view
1    1a    5.5 1    a
2     1    6.7 1     
3    2b    7.1 2    b
4    2c    8.2 2    c
5 1yolk    4.5 1 yolk
6     3    2.2 3     
7 3yolk    3.5 3 yolk
```

If you want to remove column `ID`:

```
df$ID <- NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `parse_number` to extract the numeric part and `str_remove` to remove the numeric from the 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df %>%
        mutate(n = readr::parse_number(ID),
        view = str_remove(ID, "\\d+"), ID = NULL) %>%
        select(n, view, length)
```

-output

```
df1
#  n view length
#1 1    a    5.5
#2 1         6.7
#3 2    b    7.1
#4 2    c    8.2
#5 1 yolk    4.5
#6 3         2.2
#7 3 yolk    3.5
```

---

Or can use `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   separate(ID, into = c('n', 'view'), sep = "(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z]?)")
```

-output

```
#  n view length
#1 1    a    5.5
#2 1         6.7
#3 2    b    7.1
#4 2    c    8.2
#5 1 yolk    4.5
#6 3         2.2
#7 3 yolk    3.5
```